# Fit distribution to histogram

Tags: r, histogram, curve-fitting, curve

I have the following data:

```
a <- c(rep(1/9, 80), rep(1/7, 7), rep(1/5, 7), rep(1/3, 6))
```

How do I choose the ratios 1/7, 1/5 etc as breaks for the x axis? The bars should be as broad as the intervals, i.e. first bar from 1/9-0, second bar from 1/7-1/9 etc.

How do I determine the distribution that has most likely created the data in a convenient way?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `a`, `c(...)`, `rep(...)`? What language, IDE, framework, library do you use? Add some context info.

Comment: What I need is the histogram of variable a, which can take the values of the vector c. I use RStudio 0.98.490 on OS X, with the standard framework based on R from CRAN.

Answer (score 1):

```
require("ggplot2")

a <- c(rep(1/9, 80), rep(1/7, 7), rep(1/5, 7), rep(1/3, 6))-0.0001
b <- c(1/10,1/9,1/7,1/5,1/3)

ggplot(NULL, aes(x=a)) + 
                geom_histogram(breaks = b, 
                colour = "black", fill = "lightblue")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- c(rep(1/9, 80), rep(1/7, 7), rep(1/5, 7), rep(1/3, 6))

library(ggplot2)
gg <- data.frame(a)
ggplot(gg)+
  geom_histogram(aes(x=factor(a)),fill="lightgreen")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("1/9","1/7","1/5","1/3"))+
  labs(x="a")
```

[image]

**EDIT** (Response to OP's comment)

I have a sinking feeling this is what you want:

```
df<- data.frame(table(a))   # calculate frequencies
df$xmax <- as.numeric(as.character((df$a)))
df$xmin <- c(1/10,df[-nrow(df),]$xmax)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df)+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=0, ymax=Freq),fill="lightgreen", colour="grey50")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1/10,df$xmax),labels=c("1/10","1/9","1/7","1/5","1/3"))
```

[image]

Sorry to have to say it, but this is a truly horrible way to display the data. The eye is naturally drawn to the *area*, rather than the *height*, so the frequencies are grossly distorted when you do it this way.

Comment: Thanks! I need the domain from 1/10 to 1 with 4 different intervals: 1/10-1/9, 1/9-1/7, 1/7-1/5 and 1/5-1/3 of proportional lengths (above, they all have the same length.) Each bar should fully cover its interval, i.e. one bar ranging from 1/10-1/9, the next from 1/9-1/7 etc. I appreciate your advice!